# How to display barcodes in a matrix-like structure?

Tags: java, itext, barcode

How can I display different [barcode](/questions/tagged/barcode)s in multiple columns in a PDF page using [itext](/questions/tagged/itext) library to generate pdfs in [java](/questions/tagged/java)? I have to display 12 barcodes in the same PDF page in three columns, each one contains 4 barcodes (in other words it is a 4 by 3 matrix).

Comment: I guess people are giving you downvotes because you don't show what you've tried and because it is rude to *demand* people to help you *as soon as possible*. I suggest you edit your question (or it risks being closed).

Answer (score 4):

I've made a [Barcodes](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/Barcodes) example that does exactly what you need. See the resulting pdf: [barcodes_table.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/barcode_table.pdf)

There's nothing difficult about it. You just create a table with 4 column and you add 12 cell:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    table.addCell(createBarcode(writer, String.format("%08d", i)));
}
```

The `createBarcode()` method creates a cell with a barcode:

```
public static PdfPCell createBarcode(PdfWriter writer, String code) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    BarcodeEAN barcode = new BarcodeEAN();
    barcode.setCodeType(Barcode.EAN8);
    barcode.setCode(code);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(barcode.createImageWithBarcode(writer.getDirectContent(), BaseColor.BLACK, BaseColor.GRAY), true);
    cell.setPadding(10);
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: can we left align the code for the barcode in the above code? i tried but couldnt!